# how to get bounding rectangle on both source and contour window?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

[I am using this link to get bound rectangle for contour](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)

I want to know how can I get the same rectangle on source window, which is detected in the contour window.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Answered here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/59420/how-to-get-bounding-rectangle-on-both-window/). Code by sturkmen:

```
 /**
 * @function generalContours_demo1.cpp
 * @brief Demo code to find contours in an image
 * @author OpenCV team
 */

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/**
 * @function main
 */
int main( int, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  /// Create Window
  const char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

  createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/**
 * @function thresh_callback
 */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat threshold_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using Threshold
  threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
  vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
  vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
       boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
       minEnclosingCircle( contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
     }


  /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles

  Mat src2 = src.clone(); //add this line
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, (int)i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
       rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
       circle( drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0 );


       drawContours( src2, contours_poly, (int)i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );//add this line
       rectangle( src2, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );//add this line
       circle( src2, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0 );//add this line

     }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
  imshow( "Source", src2 );//add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your polygons and circles in main( int argc, char** argv ) function.
2. namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( source_window, **drawing** );

3.Comment
createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );

thresh_callback( 0, 0 );